# Disallow only homepage ( / ) and allow all other pages for robots.txt

Tags: html, web-crawler, seo, google-search, google-crawlers

I need to prevent Google web crawler from crawling only my homepage, located in /

But I need to allow all the other pages to be crawled. How can I achieve that?

I tried doing:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following for this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /$
```

The path of the URLs is compared against the `Disallow` directives. `$` designates the end of the match pattern so the `Disallow` directive will only match `https://example.com/` but not `https://example.com/foo`.

Comment: thank you Tobias. Tried it and works like a charm!